# Why is Angular Form very slow within MatDialog component?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-cdk

I have an Angular form in a Material Dialog component.  There is data being two-way binded and when tabbing through inputs or typing in inputs results in the screen locking up for a few seconds between keydown's .   All data is passing properly but is painfully slow while trying to use the form.

I've tried refactoring the form to use  for the inputs to use a "Material form" but still has the same slowdown performance.

Here's a screenshot of performance tracker in chrome: 
[image: Slow down performance over 10 seconds.]

Is there something wrong with my configuration?  Or is this a possible regression in latest Angular 8 animation / CDK packages?  Here are my Angular package dependencies:

```
dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.13",
}
```

Here is the component method that calls the dialog:

```
public editRow(tablerow: IRule): void {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDialogComponent, {
  width: '100%',
  height: '85%',
  data: tablerow
});

this.subscriptions.push(
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(updatedRule => {
    if (updatedRule !== undefined) {

      this.rules = this.rules.map(rule => rule.Id === updatedRule.Id ? updatedRule : rule);

      this.subscriptions.push(this.dataService.updateRule(updatedRule).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SuccessComponent, {
            duration: 3000,
            data: `Rule added`
          });
        }, error => {
          this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorComponent, {
            duration: 10000,
            data: 'Internal Server Error'
          });
          }
        ));
      }
    })
  );
}
```

The mat dialog template containing the form:

```
<mat-dialog-content>
<i id="close-icon" class="material-icons md-24" aria-label="close"
[mat-dialog-close]>close</i>
<div class="brand-panel-container">
<div class="brand-panel">
  <div class="brand-panel-header">
    <div class="brand-title">
      <h4 mat-dialog-title>Rule: {{ data.Id }}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form #ruleForm="ngForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Shop Type:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <select
            [(ngModel)]="data.Type.Text"
            value="{{ data.Type.Text }}"
            name="type"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="type"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of shopTypeOpts; trackBy: indentify" value="{{opt.Text}}">{{opt.Text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Origin:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.Origin"
            value="{{ data.Origin }}"
            name="origin"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="origin"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Destination:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.Destination"
            value="{{ data.Destination }}"
            name="destination"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="destination"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Fare:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.Fare.Text"
            value="{{ data.Fare.Text }}"
            name="fare"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="fare"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Government:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <select
            [(ngModel)]="data.Government.Text"
            value="{{ data.Government.Text }}"
            name="government"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="government"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of governmentTypeOpts; trackBy: indentify"
              value="{{opt.Text}}">{{opt.Text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Special Pricing:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <select
            [(ngModel)]="data.SpecialPricing.Text"
            value="{{ data.SpecialPricing.Text }}"
            name="specialPricing"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="specialPricing"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of specialPricingTypeOpts; trackBy: indentify"
              value="{{opt.Text}}">{{opt.Text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Upgrade:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <select
            [(ngModel)]="data.Upgrade.Text"
            value="{{ data.Upgrade.Text }}"
            name="upgrade"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="upgrade"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of upgradeTypeOpts; trackBy: indentify"
              value="{{opt.Text}}">{{opt.Text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Cabin Count:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.CabinCount"
            value="{{ data.CabinCount }}"
            name="cabinCount"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="cabinCount"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Columns Count:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.ColumnsCount"
            value="{{ data.ColumnsCount }}"
            name="columnsCount"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="columnsCount"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Lang Code:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.LangCode"
            value="{{ data.LangCode }}"
            name="langCode"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="langCode"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Fare Wheel Search?:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.IsFareWheelSearch"
            value="{{ data.IsFareWheelSearch }}"
            name="isFareWheelSearch"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="isFareWheelSearch"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Markets:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <select
            [(ngModel)]="data.Markets.Text"
            value="{{ data.Markets.Text }}"
            name="markets"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="markets"
            required>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of marketTypeOpts; trackBy: indentify" value="{{opt.Text}}">{{opt.Text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">POS:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.POS"
            value="{{ data.POS }}"
            name="pos"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="pos"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Columns:<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="data.Columns"
            value="{{ data.Columns }}"
            name="columns"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="columns"
            required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
      <span *ngIf="!ruleForm.valid" class="invalid-msg"><span
          class="asterisk">*</span>All fields must be filled in to save
        changes.</span>
      <button mat-button class="brand-default-button"
        [mat-dialog-close]>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button class="brand-confirm-button" type="submit"
        [disabled]="!ruleForm.valid" [mat-dialog-close]="data.Id"
        (click)="onSaveData(ruleForm.value)">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The dialog component file:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { IRule } from '../../../models/rule.interface';
import { OptionsService } from 'src/app/shared/services/options.service';
import { IDropdownOption } from 'src/models/dropdown-option.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class EditDialogComponent {

  public shopTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];
  public governmentTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];
  public specialPricingTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];
  public fareTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];
  public upgradeTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];
  public marketTypeOpts: IDropdownOption[] = [];

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditDialogComponent>,
    public optionsService: OptionsService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: IRule) {
    this.shopTypeOpts = this.optionsService.shopTypeOptions;
    this.governmentTypeOpts = this.optionsService.governmentTypeOptions;
    this.specialPricingTypeOpts = this.optionsService.specialPricingTypeOptions;
    this.fareTypeOpts = this.optionsService.fareTypeOptions;
    this.upgradeTypeOpts = this.optionsService.upgradeTypeOptions;
    this.marketTypeOpts = this.optionsService.marketTypeOptions;
  }

  public onSaveData(updatedRule: IRule): void {
    this.dialogRef.close(updatedRule);
  }

  public indentify(index, item) {
    return item.Text;
  }

}
```

IDropdownOption interface:

```
export interface IDropdownOption {
  Text: string;
  Value: number;
}
```

***EDITED to include trackBy function & IDropdownOption interface to see unique identifier. ***

The slow down seems to be because of the dropdown options being looped over repeatedly... Maybe changeDetection strategy needs to be changed?

Comment: That nested `this.subscriptions.push(` is crazy and looks very suspicious :)

Comment: In every `*ngFor` you have, you should use a `trackBy` function. That's what slowing you down

Comment: @jsbin Yeah... I like to keep my subscriptions grouped to unsub them onDestroy but I agree this needs refactoring.   It doesn't seem to affect my performance issue however :/

Comment: @jsbin I would say it's a good way to manage multiple subscriptions by calling unsubscribe in ngDestroy via a loop.

Comment: @Phix, it visually appears like there is subscription in subscription, so feels like memory leaky place, as you would unsubscribe only the first one

Comment: But +1 for more attention. Looks interesting

Comment: @PierreDuc I have updated question to include my trackBy implementation but still facing the same issue.  It did however help me uncover that the trackBy function is being called (and the ngFor loops?) are triggering on every keydown for some reason. This I think is the source of the slowdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks so much for everyone's help.  I solved my issue by using ChangeDetectorRef in the parent component to detach once the dialog is opened, and reattached once the dialog is closed.   This prevents any re-render / re-drawing of the EditDialogComponent and fixes the performance issue.

```
public editRow(tablerow: IRule): void {

this.changeDetectorRef.detach(); // Detach change detection before the dialog opens. 

const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditDialogComponent, {
  width: '100%',
  height: '85%',
  data: tablerow
});

this.subscriptions.push(
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(updatedRule => {

    this.changeDetectorRef.reattach(); // Reattach change detection after the dialog closes.

    if (updatedRule !== undefined) {

      this.rules = this.rules.map(rule => rule.Id === updatedRule.Id ? updatedRule : rule);

      this.subscriptions.push(this.dataService.updateRule(updatedRule).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SuccessComponent, {
            duration: 3000,
            data: `Rule added`
          });
          }, error => {
            this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ErrorComponent, {
              duration: 10000,
              data: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
          }
        ));
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: in my case of table. I have directive adding glassoverlay. IF I have more than 8 items on screen it slows down even though I have onPush. I need to reduce elements from dom tree for performance boost :/ (Just found root cause: it was backdropclass property of modal causing lag!!)

Answer (score 3):

I'll make it an answer, because I think I know what's causing your slowdown. Besides the lack of `trackBy` method for your `*ngFor`, it also has to check the entire template with every input you do. It's advised to use the `OnPush` change detection strategy. This might make some things not work the way you expect them to, but it's a very good way to keep your components quick, because changes will only be checked once an Input is changed (and other things.

This is still a good [article](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4) on this subject.

You should change your dialog component decorator to include `OnPush`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-dialog.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to solve my issue without changing ChangeDetection setting. Your answer helped me go in the right direction. :)  I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is use case dependent. **Might sound weird!**

*Background:* I have implemented OnPush Strategy as well detaching reattaching ChangeDetectorRef in my custom grid/table component where few elements have glass overlay added using directive with help of renderer2

I had added blur background as 'backdropClass' property while opening dialog.

It caused a lag when the screen size is more, If I reduce screen size it's performing well. If I delete few elements from the Dom tree it performs well.

So I found it was backdrop class that was slowly applied, *resulting in an illusion of lag on the overall dialog.*

Just remove it.

Hope this helps someone who is scratching head over all solutions already implemented :)

```
 this.dialog
  .open(CreateKeyComponent, {
    disableClose: true,
    // backdropClass: 'blur',  -----> root cause
    position: { top: '15vh' },
    data: {
      data: this.tableDataShowFlag ? '1' : '0',
    },
  })
```